# How to nest this scss so that it still functions as expected

Tags: css, sass

I have a scss file that I need to orgnanize by nesting some of these properties, I've tried to nest them but the properties do not seem to work when I nest them. I was just wondering if there is a proper way to do it, thanks in advance!

This is how it is working at the moment:

```
input~.checked-icon {
  color: $primary-color;
  background-color: transparent;
  &:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

input:disabled~.checked-icon {
  color: $disabled-color;
}
```

This is what i've tried:

```
input~.checked-icon {
  color: $primary-color;
  background-color: transparent;
  &:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  &:disabled {
    color: $disabled-color;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code instead of using a picture ?

Comment: Please show what you tried, the code that errors, not just the working version. Also please post actual code, not pictures.

Comment: Thanks sorry I forgot you can post code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is creating a selector that looks like this:

```
input ~ .checked-icon:disabled {
  color: $disabled-color;
}
```

where the `:disabled` is applied to the `.checked-icon`.

The additional `:disabled` rule needs to be applied to the `input`, so you would want to use:

```css
input {

  &~.checked-icon {
    color: $primary-color;
    background-color: transparent;
    
    &:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  }
  
  &:disabled~.checked-icon {
    color: $disabled-color;
  }
}
```

Keep in mind there are lots of useful online tools for playing with Sass and viewing the compiled code. Like [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much Brett, what are you thoughts on applying styles through the input tag directly ? I am styling Material-UI components through scss modules and it seems to be quite tricky.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `class` to style them, instead of the base `input` selector.

Comment: You might also want to look into if there are any theming options.